# SVN checkout issue - SASL authentication error

Tags: svn, sasl

I wonder if anyone experienced the same issue on Windows 7 with the following error message below when checkout a SVN repository (it works perfectly on my Macbook from the same Wifi connection).

I have turned off all firewall and Antivirus softwares but no luck

```
Command: Checkout from svn://XX.XX.XX.XX/online/, revision HEAD, Fully      recursive, Externals excluded  
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://89.234.30.79/online/property'  
Error: SASL authentication error: SASL(-1): generic failure: Unable to find a  
Error:  callback: 2  
Completed!:
```

Many thanks,
Hung

Comment: It would help mentionning which SVN client you are using.

Comment: Hi there, I use TortoiseSVN and also SVN within Netbeans.

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed with different router!

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for some of my users... in my case it turned out this indicated a wrong password. Just so other people looking for this error may be warned.